# basic modulus question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So if so $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, which should be read as "$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$" which from what I understand is something among the lines of "$a$ is the remainder when $b$ is divided by $n$".

Now, given $51 \equiv 41 \pmod{5}$ means the remainder of $41$ divided by $5$ is $1$, so this is $a$? I am confused as a looks to be $51$?

Comment: $a \equiv b (\mod n )$ means $a-b$ is divisible by n

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Otherwise said: $a$ and  $b$ have the same remainder when $a$ and $b$ are divided by $n$. What you mention is denoted by $a=b\bmod n$ (note no parentheses, equality symbol  and the smaller distance between $b$ and $\mod{}$). `TeX code: `\bmod`.

Comment: $a \equiv b \pmod n \iff a \bmod n = b \bmod n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$41 \pmod 5 \equiv1\pmod5$ (This is $\frac{41}{5}, $ with a remainder of $1.$)

$51 \pmod 5 \equiv1\pmod5$ (This is $\frac{51}{5}, $ also with a remainder of $1.$)

Therefore: $41\equiv 51 \pmod 5$.

$$a\equiv1\pmod5$$

$$b\equiv1\pmod5$$